# Добавление картинки в ресурсы проекта и дальнейшее её использование

Tags: java, swing

Есть Bground.jpg в изображениях
Как добавить его в ресурсы проекта и потом установить как Bground

Проект написан на Swing, собирается внутренним сборщиком Idea.

Comment: Вопрос про swing, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да вопрос про swing

Comment: Проект Maven' ом собираете?

Comment: Нет пишу код в идее и потом как допишу сделаю jar файл

Comment: Хотелось бы потом узнать можно ли как то сделать exe

Comment: С Maven' ом знаком и Ant' ом тоже но с ними работать не умею

Comment: Gradle я вообще пропускаю

Comment: Для сборки лучше сразу использовать например Maven. Та же идея при создании проекта Maven генерит структуру по умолчанию, в которой уже тесть папка resources. Из этой папки Maven при сборке сам всё забирает по умолчанию.

Comment: Что касается exe - сгенерить точно можно - есть утилиты.

Comment: jar файл у вас идея собирает и сейчас при каждом запуске проекта, просто она это делает в скрытом от вас режиме.

Comment: Я читал на этом сайте что нельзя уходить от сути вопроса - Как добавить картинку в ресурсы проекта и потом установить её как Bground  
мы сейчас говорим про билд программы.

Comment: Мол если появился новый вопрос не касающийся данной темы нужно нажимать задать вопрос и задавать этот вопрос

Comment: Сделать фоновую картинку тоже можно - можно использовать готовый например JImagePanel.

Comment: Пишет cannot resolve symbol JImagePanel.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Image image = new Image("Папка с картинками в проекте/название картинки.png"); // создаешь экземпляр класса Image и кидаешь туда картинку.

public ImageView imageSet;

private void setImage() { // метод для установки картинки
        imageSet.setImage(image);
    }
```

ИЛИ ВОТ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466240/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать готовый JImagePanel.
Посмотреть и скопировать реализацию можете тут https://gist.github.com/sauljabin/ad45446698bc094b37d4

Суть проста, сначала создаете объект картинки `ImageIcon`, потом отрисовываете картинку на `Jpanel`

```
  graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```